# POCO and non-POCO in the same class library project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In one of my projects I have some models that I don't want to use with POCO i.e. use the EF generated classes and some others where I want to use POCOs. When I mix those, the POCO mapping doesn't work and I get an exception

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx'.
  Source=System.Data.Entity

This message usually is something incorrect in connection string. However, after through inspection I could confirm that there is nothing wrong with that or the generated POCO classes. I also found that

Mapping POCO entities is not supported if any mapping attributes are applied to custom data classes, including EdmSchemaAttribute at the assembly level.

in MSDN article [Working with POCO Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853%28VS.100%29.aspx). While the simplest solution is to split the project into two parts and keep POCO and non-POCO separately, I wanted to see if there is another way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a way to this.

Comment: Looks like there isn't a way to do this?